# Open elements in .txt file as lists and not as strings

Tags: python, string

I wrongly saved a list of lists as a .txt file, and now when I open it my lists are considered to be strings, like the following:

```
mylist = ['[1,2,3,4,5]', '[4,47,6,7,3,9]',...]
```

Is there a way to open the file and not read the lists as strings?
What I tried:

```
my_new_list = []
for item in mylist:
    new_item = eval(item)
    my_new_list.append(new_item)
```

But then I get the error:
    new_item = eval(item)

```
File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Is there a way to open my file without reading the lists as strings (I would like to avoid having to run my program again and saving the file in another way)? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `eval`, use `ast.literal_eval` Are you sure all of your `item`s are valid? But no, there's no way to open a text file "as lists".

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried with `ast.literal_eval`, but I have the same problem. How can I check if they are valid? if I try to print the elements in the list, I have no problem, the problem is that I cannot append them to a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. The problem is at the end of file (EOF). Verify the last element of your mylist

```
mylist = ['[1,2,3,4,5]', '[4,47,6,7,3,9]']

my_new_list = []
for item in mylist:
    new_item = eval(item)
    my_new_list.append(new_item)
print (my_new_list)
```

Answer: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 47, 6, 7, 3, 9]]

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for the heads up! The problem was that the last element was `' '`, for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads` to convert each individual string to list. Avoid using `eval` as it can cause security issues

Using `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> import ast
>>> mylist = ['[1,2,3,4,5]', '[4,47,6,7,3,9]']
>>> [ast.literal_eval(e) for e in mylist]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 47, 6, 7, 3, 9]]
```

Using `json.loads`

```
>>> import json
>>> mylist = ['[1,2,3,4,5]', '[4,47,6,7,3,9]']
>>> [json.loads(e) for e in mylist]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 47, 6, 7, 3, 9]]
```

Comment: This only works coincidentally - Python serialisation is *not* always the same as JSON.

Comment: For this example, I know it would work. Thats why I suggested

Comment: But you should at least *mention* that in the answer. It's a pretty big caveat.